# how can we set different tag values to each cell in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone

i am new to iphone. i want to set different tag values to each cell in table view.for example I have a table view with 6cells.Here i want to set tag value to 1st cell is 4 and tagvalue to 2nd cell is 1 like that for all 6 cells we have to set 6 different values.
If any body know this please help me...

Comment: Is there any kind of scheme to the way you are tagging them?  And for what purpose do you need the cells to be tagged?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the like this...

```
 cell.tag = indexPath.row + 1..
```

it will set your cell tag as 1 to 6...

may this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You may set the tag value within the TableViewControler's cellForRowAtIndexPath method. There you should have all data available, that is known to the view controller and you have access to each cell that is about to be displayed.

As UITableViewCell inherits from UIView just type

```
cell.tag = value; //with value being what you want to assing in this case.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having fixed number of cells, you can do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` by checking each cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.tag = 4;
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            cell.tag = 1;
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 2)
        {
            ...so on
        }
        return cell;
  }
```